# String treatment google sheets

Tags: regex, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to handle numbers in google sheets, I need to insert punctuation in it.

Example:

I need this:
[image]

turn this:
[image]

Always in the same pattern, I have a list of numbers.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function reorder() {
  const a = ["12345678901234567890","12345678901234567890"];//put all of the strings into an array
  const b = a.map(s => {
    return `${s.slice(0,7)}-${s.slice(7,9)}.${s.slice(9,13)}.${s.slice(13,14)}.${s.slice(14,16)}.${s.slice(16)}`
  })
  Logger.log(b.join('\n'))
}

Execution log
12:34:02 PM Notice  Execution started
12:34:03 PM Info    1234567-89.0123.4.56.7890
                    1234567-89.0123.4.56.7890
12:34:04 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Or this:

```
function reorder() {
  const a = ["12345678901234567890","12345678901234567890"];
  const b = a.map(s => s.replace(/(\w{7})(\w{2})(\w{4})(\w)(\w{2})(\w{4})/, "$1-$2.$3.$4.$5.$6"));
  Logger.log(b.join('\n'))
}

Execution log
12:48:51 PM Notice  Execution started
12:48:52 PM Info    abcdefg-89.0123.4.56.7890
                    1234567-89.0123.4.56.7890
12:48:52 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

In a spreadsheet:

```
function reorder() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const a = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const b = a.map(s => [s.replace(/(\w{7})(\w{2})(\w{4})(\w)(\w{2})(\w{4})/, "$1-$2.$3.$4.$5.$6")]);
  sh.getRange(1,2,b.length,b[0].length).setValues(b);
}
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| abcdefg8901234567890 | abcdefg-89.0123.4.56.7890 |
| 12345678901234567890 | 1234567-89.0123.4.56.7890 |

Comment: Can you share a screenshot how it used?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean.  You provide it and array of 20 character strings and it separates them for you.  You do want you want with them

Comment: is it a function"formula" that can take a range A1:A5 and output a result or you need to go to appscript and paste the input in the [] array? Im new to appscript.

Comment: It's a google apps script like one of your tags

Comment: Im not the OP, just testing answers

Comment: Worked well. But in the case how do I change only the selected files, I tried this but it didn't work: const sh= ss.getSelection().getActiveRange();

Comment: @GabrielPassos Ask new questions in new post.

Comment: @GabrielPassos I don't understand what you are asking.  I simply gave to a couple of techniques as to how to add white space between characters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number strings are in column `A2:A`, use this regex formula:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    regexreplace( 
      A2:A, 
      "(\d{7})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d)(\d{2})(\d{4})", 
      "$1-$2.$3.$4.$5.$6"
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

If you want to do this with Apps Script, use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and the same regex parameters as in the spreadsheet formula above. Note that Google Apps Script uses [JavaScript regexes](https://regexr.com/).